# Prove that the following expression is always less than x for all values of x and k.

Tags: calculus

Prove that

$$\frac{x^2+kx}{2x+k}$$

is less than x for all values of x and k where x>0,  k>0 and k is a constant.

How would I prove this? I have differentiated it with respect to x and noticed that the derivative is always less than 1 for all values of x and k, this means that if the value of x increases the value out always increases less than the increase in x.

Comment: +1, but please try and be careful to get things right when writing questions as editing after having gotten answers had can sometimes be interpreted as disrespectful.

Answer (score 1):

Multiplying by $2x+k$ positive, $$x^2+kx<x(2x+k)$$

then

$$x^2>0.$$

---

Alternatively,

$$\frac{x^2+kx}{2x+k}-x=-\frac{x^2}{2x+k}<0.$$

Comment: Sorry I wrote down the expression wrong. Edited.

Comment: I made mistakes myself. Everything fixed now.